# Error in Sending Email using php

Tags: php, email

I am sending email using php script and i am setting from address as

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "$from" . "\r\n";
$headers.= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
```

So, the mail coming to my mail address as from `support@mysite.com`, But i need to set from address as `support@gmail.com`.But it is not coming with the modified from address. So, please help to solve this problem..

Comment: Have you seen in spam? may be you get your message in spam.

Comment: yes, but email is coming inbox as from address "support@mysite.com", not from "support@gmail.com".. please help me..

Comment: Even if this email will be shown to come from gmail.com when you open full source of email, you will see that it wasn't sent from Google SMTPs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace header text,

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" . 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP \r\n";
$headers .= "From: YourName <support@gmail.com>";
```

[To get more information about mail function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

may this help you.

Answer (score 1):

You try this...

```
<?php
  $to      = 'nobody@example.com';
  $subject = 'Mail Subject';
  $message = 'Test';
  $headers = 'From: support@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
  'Reply-To: support@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

?>

Hop this will works...